# Why does addEventListener poping out an error on Dream Weaver?

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

[image]

Can anyone could help me? Why does the addEventListener poping out an error on Dream Weaver but it is working perfectly on solo learn

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Don't use dream weaver, this is a dead program.

Comment: Dream Weaver probably doesn't know about arrow function syntax.

Comment: It likely doesn't recognize arrow functions. Like cloned said, it's an old dead program..

Comment: My guess is Dream Weaver does not know [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How are they supposed to post about problems in a GUI application without a screenshot?

Comment: @Barmar - There's no reason they can't *also* have a screenshot. But the error, and any code related to it, should be in the question *as text*. Perhaps I should add "just" to my stock comment, though frankly I would have thought it was clear enough.